# Phonegap/Cordova, how to communicate with other devices

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

is it possible, in you opinion, to build a Phonegap Android App that can work on wi-fi and push/pull information between all the devices that are connected on the same network ? Ideally this application should:

- work without any external server/service (the local network can be disconnected from internet)
- automatically find all devices that are running the same application when they are available
- broadcast datas in **real-time**
- **pull** datas pushed from other devices
- **push** datas to all available devices

I think socket.io can be the right candidate, but I wonder if someone have any advice about the right cordova plugin to use (or point-me to an how-to? ). Sorry I'm pretty new to Phonegap and their plugin list is about 1600 items long.